# Excel Copy Words Which Start with "Acc" From Column A to B

Tags: vba, excel

[Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi1Ol.jpg)

[image]

I would like a an automation developed.

Starting from A2 move contents of A2 into B3 and B4 then move contents A5 into B6 to B8, then A9 into B10 and so forth to the end

of the records

The logic is if cell AX has string starting with "Acc" move contents into cell  BX+1 If next cell AX+2 is not starting with "Acc"

then copy cell BX above and so forth till end of the data.

Stop when cell AX is blank.
Here is my code i tried but its not working

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim recSheet As Worksheet
 Set recSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("original")

loop through column A and find words
'which starts with "Acc" if next cell is not starting with "Acc"

LastRow = recSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
NextRow = recSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

 For i = 2 To LastRow

   If Range("A" & i).Value = "Acc*" And NextRow <> "Acc*" Then
    Range("A" & i).Select
    Selection.Cut

     Range("B" & i").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It should be "cut" not "copy"

Comment: Please explain how it is "not working". Does it do something other than expected? Does it do nothing? Does it cause an error message (if so, what is it)? Does Excel crash? Does Excel become unresponsive?

Comment: nothing is happening and no errors too

Comment: You should add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and `Dim` (declare) your variables. If you do that you will get an error at `NextRow <> "Acc*"` because you are trying to compare a number with a string.

Comment: i have added Option Explicit and now i have an error " Variable not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim texttocopy as String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim recSheet As Worksheet
    Set recSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("original")
    lastrow = recSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        texttocopy = Range("A" & i).Value
        If Range("A" & i).Value Like "Acc*" And Not Range("A" & i + 1).Value Like "Acc*" Then
            i = i + 1
            Do While Not Range("A" & i).Value Like "Acc*" And Range("A" & i).Value <> ""
'                Range("A" & i).Select
'                Selection.Cut
'                Range("B" & i).Select
'                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Range("B" & i).Value = texttocopy
                If i >= lastrow Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Loop
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @RobinsHarawa there is a `Not` missing in the second condition so maybe there are simply no matches.

Comment: @RobinsHarawa can you please show some screen shots of whats your expected result?

Comment: i have a screen short but i don't know to upload it here in the comment box

Comment: There is an edit option available at below questions . go through there and you can able to upload your screenshot by cilcking the Image icon (available at 5th left to right).

Comment: sorry to bother you but i can't find where you are talking about. your email please i can attach it and it ll be easy

Comment: Not enough Robin i understood your requirment. Will post within a second.

Comment: i have seen it and i have added "Option Explicit" but nothing is happening.
Note: I have added 
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
because there was compile error "type missmatch"

Comment: Nan Avan Illai-the code is able to cut and paste but it is getting dates as well. I only need those words which starts with "Acc" to be move from column A to B so much that i end up with, 25-09-2013 Account Code 190..

Comment: it first gave an error "undefined variable" then i declared "texttocopy" as Range. upon doing this i get this error "Run-time error, object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: declare texttocopy as string

Comment: Thank you  very much Nan Avan Illai it has worked the way i wanted

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer and useful by accepting tick symbol in my post and up arrow for useful